# EditText GIF insertion gives null always

Tags: java, android, gif

I have used code from StackOverflow and Google. This is it:

```
editText.setKeyBoardInputCallbackListener(new EditTextGIF.KeyBoardInputCallbackListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                int flags, Bundle opts) {
        // you will get your gif/png/jpg here in opts bundle
        Log.d(TAG, "Opts: "+opts);
    }
});
```

This is EditText:

```
<com.myapp.EditTextGIF
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
    android:background="@null"
    android:maxLength="@integer/max_chat_message_length"
    android:hint="@string/type_a_message" />
```

This is the class `EditTextGIF`:

```
public class EditTextGIF extends AXEmojiEditText {

    private KeyBoardInputCallbackListener keyBoardInputCallbackListener;

    public EditTextGIF(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextGIF(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
        final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);
        EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, new String [] {"image/gif"});

        final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
                new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                                   int flags, Bundle opts) {
                        Logg.dr("Opts: " + opts);
                        // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                        if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                                InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                            try {
                                inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                return false; // return false if failed
                            }
                        }

                        // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                        // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.
                        if (keyBoardInputCallbackListener != null) {
                            keyBoardInputCallbackListener.onCommitContent(inputContentInfo, flags, opts);
                        }

                        return true;  // return true if succeeded
                    }
                };
        return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback);
    }

    public interface KeyBoardInputCallbackListener {
        void onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                             int flags, Bundle opts);
    }

    public void setKeyBoardInputCallbackListener(KeyBoardInputCallbackListener keyBoardInputCallbackListener) {
        this.keyBoardInputCallbackListener = keyBoardInputCallbackListener;
    }
}
```

It extends `AXEmojiEditText`, which is from a 3rd party [library](https://github.com/Aghajari/AXEmojiView) for an emoji keyboard.

But this code does not work properly. When I try to insert a GIF, it no longer displays the "GIFs-not-allowed-toast", but the Logs always say that the bundle `opts` I am receiving is null. No matter which GIF I choose. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Which `opts` is null? Is it both?

Comment: Yes, both are null

Comment: Well, it is hard to find to problem without the whole source code in hand. There are some redundant variables like `ic` and `callback`. I'd first check if the methods `onCreateInputConnection()` and `onCommitContent()` are called. Secondly, remove the `ic` variable (Maybe `callback` as well). Third, I'd just return `new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener()` instance. I've noticed that you've never return `callback` instance either.